# Prevent https access to domain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

We're seeing some minor issues with a cache and https on a non-secure site/domain.

The site doesn't have a certificate and therefore is not https. URLs are generated dynamically on the site though, so if someone manually visits the site using https, https will be used in the relative URLs - this is an issue for images and external resources as they then get blocked.

On an individual basis this doesn't worry me, the real issue is that if the above happens on a page that hasn't yet been cached, the cache reflects the https error in the URLs, and attempts to serve https resources to normal users, thereby leaving all external resources blocked. We've just seen this happen on a set of pages.

I have no idea why someone would be attempting to access the site using https, but unfortunately it seems to happen.

Is there any way to route all https traffic directly to http? It's a frustrating issue as the site doesn't purport to be secure, doesn't have a certificate, and therefore security issues like this are meaningless - ideally https requests should just be being parsed as http.

Any help appreciated!

Edit:

Turns out after some research that this may not be possible. The method suggested in the comments should work (with the addition of an on/off flag for the condition), however it only works if SSL is available. i.e. if https isn't working in the first place, it doesn't seem you can build conditions around it.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} On
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`

Comment: Ah, excellent, thanks. Rewrite rules are a bit of a dark art for me, but that looks like it makes sense, will give it a spin!

Comment: Oops, generated an internal server error - any obvious typos or similar?

Comment: Try with `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443`